# Why won't my title information show up?

Tags: titles

I'm just beginning to learn how to use latex and I already ran into a little bind. I've been using the Latex Document wiki as my guide. The editor I'm writing the typesetting in is TeXworks. So here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\title{it's so hard out here}
\author{your main man}
\date
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
i'll start that right here
\end{abstract}


now it is time to g et to typesetting effectively
\end{document}
```

Now the problem I'm having is that my title information is not showing up when I convert to a pdf. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I delete the `latex3` tag, as it has nothing to do with latex3 basically

Comment: Your `\date` command is wrongly used. It eat's up `\maketitle` and nothing is shown from the title.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I do wonder what would happen though if `\maketitle` were inserted again.  Would TeX run itself into the ground?  It's just a raw `\def`, right?

Comment: @SeanAllred: I've just checked... you're right. `TeX capacity exceeded` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Just tested – looks like it expands `\@date` before it does the relaxation (which makes sense): `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].`  …Huh :-)

Comment: I apologize for the wrong usage of English grammar: (my bad: `eats up` of course)

Answer (score 5):

`\date` needs an argument, i.e. a date, 'enclosed' with a `{}` pair. If this is not prevalent, `\date` uses the next token it can find, i.e. `\maketitle` in the OP's post. This is bad of course, as `\date` itself is not used as long `\maketitle` is not issued.

Principally, `\date` is not necessary at all if the current date is requested. (`\maketitle` uses `\today` then)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\title{it's so hard out here}
\author{your main man}
\date{1/1/2015}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
i'll start that right here
\end{abstract}


now it is time to get to typesetting effectively
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I was reading the latex wiki it mentioned that if I live the \date blank that it would insert the current date automatically. How would that action occur? Or should I continue with the basics I'm learning?

Comment: @dc3rd: I think you misinterpreted that statement. *blank* refers to `\date{}`, not just `\date` without `{}`

Comment: @dc3rd: Errors of beginners, as we all did once ;-) (And still do :-))