# Why isn't my title showing up?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, titles, article

Note: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228065/85086)'s answer does not apply to my question.

I've written just about the simplest `.tex` file I can imagine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{The Influence of Dopamine on GABAergic and Glutamatergic
  Transmission in the Prefrontal Cortex}
\end{document}
```

When I generate a `.pdf` file from this, the title doesn't appear.  When I add text between my call to `\title` and my call to `\end`, that text appears, but the title, still, does not.

What am I doing wrong?  What is the right way to use the `\title` command?

Comment: You need `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\title{}` just tells LaTeX what the title is. It doesn't produce any output. To actually typeset the title, use `\maketitle`.

```
\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\date{}% if you don't want a date
\maketitle
```

Comment: any way to have `\maketitle` not put the date?

Comment: @dbliss Please see edit.